# Flash Game on android

Tags: android, flash

I am thinking of developing a game. I want to know if it will be safe if I write it in flash, or will any one be able to decode my code in flash ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of obfuscation tools to protect from decompilers .I don't think obfuscating will prevent the code from being decompiled. It just makes it harder to decompile. For flash , check out

[Kindi](http://www.kindi.com/)
,

[doSWF](http://www.doswf.com/)